# Upload file with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

i am trying to upload a file with spring, but when i run the app, i get :
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported

My Cotroller class is:

```
package com.tu.Main;

@Controller
public class FileUpload {



private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(FileUpload.class);

/**
 * Upload single file using Spring Controller
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}

/**
 * Upload multiple file using Spring Controller
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadMultipleFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String[] names,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) {

    if (files.length != names.length)
        return "Mandatory information missing";

    String message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = files[i];
        String name = names[i];
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            message = message + "You successfully uploaded file=" + name
                    + "<br />";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

upload.jsp

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>

<head>

<title>Upload File Request Page</title>

</head>

<body>


<form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

My servlet-context.xml is:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"


xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />


<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tu.Main" />

</beans:beans>
```

Can someone helps me?? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Which request fails? For which URL?

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:8888/Main/uploadFile

Comment: So you got the error when you pointed your browser to that URL or when you submitted the form? (Please enable debug logging with Spring and post the relevant logs here.)

Comment: I get the error when i point my browser to that URL.

Comment: Which part of your Spring app do you expect to handle that request? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the Get method for getting the input page.
You miss something like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```